# Extract Data from file and output to user space (Spacing)?

Tags: c++, pdf

I'm trying to make the link between device space and user space when parsing pdf files.  I pretty much have the data extraction squared away but when calculating the translations and using character spacing of the device space, how can I adapt this to a user space such as a console or a text file etc?

What I'm asking is this.  If I get an output which indicates that the character spaces or a translation should be .21 for example, what does this mean if I am outputting to a console or a text file?  How is that .21 distance reflected in a text file?  This leads me to believe that I'm missing a major point.

Could it be that this depends on the Font size of the output to that text file?  For example, how much is a space (using the spacebar on my keyboard)?  Is it more than .21 ?   I think I'm missing a fundamental point which is preventing me from making this link between the data I have extracted and the output space I decide to use.

I understand all about the transformation matricies etc.  That's straight forward now.  It's the adaption I'm having trouble with.

I'm using c++.

Comment: This is a good question and I would have to say I don't know.  I think it would have to do with the size of the Font being utilized in the user space you are transferring to.  I will be very interested to see what others have to say about this.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it might have been font. I am just not sure how to apply it.

Comment: *what does this mean if I am outputting to a console or a text file?* - Coordinates, distances, etc in PDF files are given assuming an output device with more flexible glyph positioning capabilities than text files. To interpret those values sensibly, you need to keep more information in memory while parsing than the mere text: positions and widths. In the context of these information you can decide what gaps mean.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a fixed width and a proportional font? Do you know what kerning is? Tracking? Justification? Do you need to be able to differ between microspacing (kerning, tracking, justification), "actual" spaces (whose width will vary with different fonts and justification [but not with font size]) and tabs, which also can be represented by a large horizontal move?

Comment: That's a good point Jongware and seems to go to the root of the question. Agreed that glyph positioning would have to be more flexible.  But if I was to interpret the output to a text file would I be looking at the font used in the text file and make my own judjements for that or would I use some kind of a standard measure for a space for example?

Comment: Again, thanks for showing me what you know and how little I know about the topic.  That's the sole reason I bothered to ask Jongware.  I thought you may elaborate a little bit but explaining how to go about understanding where to begin looking for the default fonts for my console or text file and then maybe providing a tip / direction to how you would go about it.  I didn't ask you to lay it out for me, just some direction.  I know what kerning and justification is but none of that helps if you can't imagine which kerning and justification to apply.

Comment: mkl, what kind of information?  Can you provide a hint on how to go about such a thing?   Thanks